# Jquery & KendoUI dropdown create dynamically

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I want create Kendo Dropdown dynamically using Jquery. I need to created everything in Jquery.
I've used below code, but it is creating only input textbox, but not converting into DDl.

```
var kendoddl = $("<input id=color value=1 />");

                   $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
                       dataTextField: action.Name,
                       dataValueField: action.Name,
                       dataSource: action,
                       index: 0
                   });

                   $("#addconfigurations").append(kendoddl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reorder your code. First add append and then add call kendoDropDownList

```
var kendoddl = $("<input id=color value=1 />");

$("#addconfigurations").append(kendoddl);

$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: action.Name,
      dataValueField: action.Name,
      dataSource: action,
      index: 0
});
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/azOJ

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to insert option values but not working.  
var kendoddl = $("<input id=color value=1 />");

$("#addconfigurations").append(kendoddl);

$("#color").kendoDropDownList({
     
});

$("#color").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.add({ text: "Five", value: "5" });